# Inserting Custom Panoramas Into Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The forum on the Google Maps JavaScript API group referred my question to Stack Overflow so here goes--
I'm looking to place markers on a Google map that when clicked display a streetview panorama (a "photosphere") of that location. Each panorama was stitched together from photos I've taken personally and is saved on my computer i.e. not currently publicly viewable on Google maps. 
I've searched through this guide:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview
for help but to no avail (I thought the "Providing Custom StreetView Panoramas" section might have been helpful but it didn't seem relevant, unless I misunderstood what it was saying). 
I'm aware that Google recently introduced a new way to upload personally-made photospheres for public display on Google maps (see: https://www.google.com/maps/views/home?gl=us&hl=en-us), but this is not what I want to do. 
Anyway I'd really appreciate recommendations for tutorials that might help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-simple

It has the sample code. Just make changes to use your image and you are good to go.